# How do I reference members of other types in the XML docs for a method?

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I have the following XML doc segment on one of my methods:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the total charge for hours between the <see cref="StartDateTime"/> and <see cref="EndDateTime"/> of all all the <see cref="VehiclePresence"/> records 
    /// included in the date range defined by <paramref name="startDate"/> and <paramref name="endDate"/>.
    /// </summary>
```

The `<see cref="StartDateTime"/>` part renders as `[!:StartDateTime]`. I would prefer it rendered as a link to the `VehiclePresence.StartDatetTime` property's documentation, just as the `<see cref="VehiclePresence"/>` part renders as a link to the `VehiclePresence` class's documentation.

Comment: Have you tried `<see cref="VehiclePresence.StartDateTime"/>` ?

Comment: @Carko, matter of fact I had, but several days ago. Just maybe I had forgotten to include the other project's help source, but it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
<see cref="VehiclePresence.StartDateTime"/>
```

to reference the types in the other namespaces